# Як правильно українською сказати "account" соціальньої мережі?

Tags: переклад, вживання-слів, from-english

Широко вживається слово "акаунт" - "Створи свій акаунт в фейсбук". Це правильний переклад чи варто якось по іншому перекладати?

[Google](https://translate.google.com/?hl=ru#en/uk/account) слово "account" перекладає як "рахунок".

На сайті [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/akaunt) пропонують декілька варіантів перекладу:

> - обліковка
> - обліковий запис
> - профіль
> - електрона облікова комірка

На мою думку, найбільш влучним є профіль або можна сказати особистий профіль.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follower має рацію, що *user account* і *user profile* — не одне й те саме, хоча різниця вже майже стерлася.

***Обліковий запис* — нормативний вираз, який вживають Google, Microsoft, Верховна Рада, Mozilla, Facebook, Pinterest, Samsung й інші**.

***Акаунт*** (з одним -к-, бо в загальних назвах іншомовного походження подвоєння зазвичай не зберігаються), іноді ***екаунт*** або, як пропонує follower, ***акавнт*** — **поки що на правах сленгу**.

Різні скорочення від *обліковий запис*, зокрема запропонована Олександром Пономаревим ***обліківка*** і не знаю, наскільки відповідна правилам мови, ***обліковка*** — **наскільки я знаю, теж**.

Answer (score 5):

<sup>⅔-відповідь, наприклад поясню, своїм баченням, чому „профіль“ не є *найвлучнішим*.</sup>

Слово *профіль* теж запозичене і вже закріплене, очевидно, під вживаним [*profile*](//dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/profile). На перший погляд може здатися, що вони сутямки, [деякі](//drive.google.com/file/d/1mJcpvbLuVsjiEpvySqnKbKv0flhOoDvL) так і вживають, але, по-моєму, ж ні:

- *Профіль* — сторінка чи кубло сторінок, що [представляє](/u/585/) когось чи чогось. [Далі](//storinka-m.kiev.ua/article.php?id=1323) не розглядатиму цього слово, оскільки для цього треʼ инше запитання.
- [*Акавнт*](//dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/account) — це щось, що дає доступ до осідка, наприклад через вхід з паролем, і деяких речей, як той ж профіль.

Таким чином залишаємо *акавнт*. Можна вдаритися до чистомовства, тоді слово *обліковка*, чи доречніше [*обліківка*](//bbc.com/ukrainian/blog-olexandr-ponomariv-38107976), загалом може підходити за [означенням](http://sum.in.ua/s/oblik).

Comment: profile - це опис (найкраще влучає в усіх випадках, не бачив, де б не підійшло), а описувати вже можна по різному

Answer (score 4):

На мою думку, найкращим питомим терміном є *обліківка*. Спробую обґрунтувати разом з протиставленням іншим питомим варіантам.

1. Чому *обліківка* замість *обліковка*? (на додачу до вже згаданого коментаря проф. О. Пономаріва)

- згідно з пунктом 12 §32 розділу "Правопис суфіксів" [**українського правопису 2019**](https://mon.gov.ua/ua/osvita/zagalna-serednya-osvita/navchalni-programi/ukrayinskij-pravopis-2019), перевага надається суфіксам **-івк-**(а) (**-ївк-**(а):

> -ІВК-(А), -ОВК-(А)
>
> 12. В іменниках жіночого роду, утворених від іменників та інших частин мови, уживаємо суфікс **-івк-**(а) (**-ївк-**(а): *голі́вка, долі́вка*,
>     *ножі́вка, полі́вка, спирті́вка, часті́вка, шалі́вка, шихті́вка*. У
>     деяких іменниках маємо суфікс **-овк-**(а): *голо́вка* (капусти), *духовка*.

- якщо звернутись до [**Російсько-українського академічного словника А. Кримського**](https://r2u.org.ua/html/krym_details.html) і шукати серед українських слів без цитат, то за запитом `*овка` видає лише [83 статті](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=ukr&dicts=1&highlight=on), а за запитом `*івка` кількість результатів [перевищує обмеження рушія проєкту **r2u** у 150 статей](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=ukr&dicts=1&highlight=on) і таким чином остання форма вбачається поширенішою.

2. Чому *обліківка* замість *обліковий запис*?

- згідно з пунктом Г.2 додатку Г чинного стандарту **ДСТУ 3966-2009 Термінологічна робота. Засади і правила розроблення стандартів на терміни та визначення понять**, термін має задовольняти вимогу **раціональної стислості**. Далі цитую пункти Г.2.4 та Г.4.4:

> Г.2.4 Раціональна стислість терміна
>
> Г.2.4.1 Нестислий термін — це істотна вада. Занадто довгі та громіздкі
> терміни треба скорочувати. Є кілька способів такого скорочування (див.
> Г.4.4).
>
> Г.2.4.2 За неможливості створити оптимально короткий термін,
> стандартизують повну й коротку форми терміна, використовуючи круглі
> дужки: *відшарування (лакофарбового покриву)*. Коротка форма терміна
> *відшарування* є дозволеним замінником його повної форми.
>
> Г.2.4.3 Скорочуючи довжину терміна, треба стежити, щоб не було
> вилучено з його складу важливого терміноелемента, що порушуватиме
> поняттєву сутність терміна.

> Г.4.4 Скорочування
>
> Щоб уникнути громіздкості термінів, використовують
> кілька способів скорочування. Найпоширеніші з них наведено нижче.
>
> Г.4.4.1. Вилучення зі складу терміна малоінформативних слів.
> Наприклад, замість *конвеєрна електропіч неперервної дії* треба подати
> *конвеєрна піч*. Піч такого типу належить до печей неперервної дії.
>
> Г.4.4.2 Замінення багатоелементних термінів якомога коротшими:
>
> - синонімом (*оптичний квантовий генератор — лазер*);
> - складним багатокореневим прикметником (*пристрій для вловлювання пилу та газу — пилогазовловлюваний пристрій*) або багатокореневим іменником
>   (*пилогазовловлювач*);
> - скороченнями різних типів (*система керування базами даних — СКБД*; *надвисокочастотний генератор — НВЧ-генератор*; *державна автоінспекція — ДАІ*; *доктор* (у назві вченого ступеня) — *д-р*; *година* (при цифрі) — *год*);
> - символословами (*СО-лазер*, *У-подібна муфта*);
> - коротшими словотворчими елементами терміна (*гальмівна здатність — гальмівність*, *запам'ятовувальний пристрій — запам'ятовувач*).

Таким чином, на підставі пункту Г.2.4.1 та за умови виконання пункту Г.2.4.3 *обліковий запис* скорочується до *обліківка*, як показано на прикладі *гальмівна здатність — гальмівність*, *запам'ятовувальний пристрій — запам'ятовувач* у пункті Г.4.4.2.

3. Чому *обліківка* замість *акаунт/акавнт*? Вирішив додати цей пункт, бо в деяких читачів може виникнути таке питання.

- згідно з пунктом Г.2 додатку Г чинного стандарту **ДСТУ 3966-2009 Термінологічна робота. Засади і правила розроблення стандартів на терміни та визначення понять**, термін має задовольняти вимогу **переважності рідної мови**. Далі цитую пункт Г.2.8:

> Г.2.8 Переважність рідної мови
>
> У термінотворенні перевагу слід віддавати власне українським термінам
> перед запозиченими іншомовними
> термінами. У 5.1.5 ДСТУ 1.5 зазначено: «У стандарті заборонено вживати
> іншомовні слова і терміни за наявності рівнозначних слів і термінів в
> українській мові». Треба вживати слова *відсоток*, а не *процент*,
> *чинник*, а не *фактор*, словосполуку *продавати*, *збувати товар*, а не *реалізовувати товар* тощо. Використовують звичайно слова
> іншомовного походження, якщо немає тотожних українських відповідників
> (*атом, дискета, сальдо*). Іноді запозичені терміни в термінологічних
> стандартах можна подавати як синоніми.